# Adding Tabs in Odoo Application Index File

Tags: odoo, odoo-ce, odoo-17

I have tried adding tabs in odoo index file but it is not working. I have tried various ways that works in an HTML file but it does not work in odoo Index file.

In Odoo app index file buttons and click events also don't work. But some apps has tabs in their index file we can see on Odoo App Store. Can someone help me with how to add tabs in Odoo app index file?

Thanks In Advance !!!

I Tried how we add tabs in form view :

````
<notebook>
    <page string="Tab 1">
        <!-- Contents of Tab 1 -->
    </page>
    <page string="Tab 2">
        <!-- Contents of Tab 2 -->
    </page>
     <!-- Add more pages as needed -->
</notebook>```



I tried this html solution as well :

`your text`

But in odoo index file <script/> <style/> <button/> and external css / js links don't work.
````

Comment: could you be more clear? seems that you already know how to extend views to add page to a notebook. What's the problem?